# Multipying and adding inside of a too large array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array A that is of the shape (M,N) now I'd like to do the operation

`R = (A[:,newaxis,:] * A[newaxis,:,:]).sum(2)`

which should yield an (MxM) array. Now the problem is that the array is quite large and I get a Memory error, because the MxMxN array won't fit into memory.

what would be the best strategy to get this done?
C? map()? or is there a special function for this yet?

thank you,
David

Comment: Is `A` really an MxN array? I guess `A[:,newaxis,:]` is an MxN array. Even then, `A[:,newaxis,:] * A[newaxis,:,:]` should yield a 2-dimensional array, so I don't understand `sum(2)`, because there is no third axis (or newaxis is a slice, not a single number). Something's missing here.

Comment: Depending on the precision required, you could attempt to use a different type for the values inside the array. Eg, `numpy.float32`, or `numpy.int16`. That could halve your memory requirements.

Comment: @Evert A[:,np.newaxis,:].shape == (M,1,N) and (A[:,np.newaxis,:] * A[np.newaxis,:,:]).shape == (M,M,N)

Comment: Ok, I missed the `newaxis`, that's new to me, and it didn't have a `np` namespace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure how large you arrays are but the following is equivalent:

```
R = np.einsum('ij,kj',A,A)
```

And can be quite a bit faster and is much less memory intensive:

```
In [7]: A = np.random.random(size=(500,400))

In [8]: %timeit R = (A[:,np.newaxis,:] * A[np.newaxis,:,:]).sum(2)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.21 s per loop

In [9]: %timeit R = np.einsum('ij,kj',A,A)
10 loops, best of 3: 54 ms per loop
```

If I increase the size of `A` to `(500,4000)`, `np.einsum` plows through the calculation in about 2 seconds, whereas the original formulation grinds my machine to a halt due to the size of the temporary array it has to create.

**Update**:

As @Jaime pointed out in the comments, `np.dot(A,A.T)` is also an equivalent formulation of the problem, and can be even faster than the `np.einsum` solution. Full credit to him for pointing that out, but in case he doesn't post it as a formal solution, I wanted to pull it out into the main answer.

Comment: +1 But the OP's calculation is also equivalent to `np.dot(A, A.T)`, and on my system, for a `(500, 400)` shaped array, it is about 10x faster than `np.einsum`, which is already 6x faster than the OP's method.

Comment: @Jaime good catch. Post that as an answer and I'll upvote it. fwiw, `np.dot` is only about 2.5 faster than `np.einsum` on my machine for (500,400). For (500,4000) though `np.dot` is about 10x faster.

Comment: I am a reputation whore, just not that much... ;-) Feel free to post the timings of `np.dot` if you want to, I think it will be cleaner with a single answer.

Comment: thanks you guys that looks very helpful! I'll try it out monday morning